# "no mapping found" error java spring MVC with no xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, web, sencha-touch-2

i'm new in Spring + MVC.
i've found a script and i could run some part of this script.
this script configuring spring mvc with no xml, inside java side.
i put all the jars into WEB-INF/lib.

**ControllerConfiguration .java**

```
package org.java.springmvc.bootstrap;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.java.springmvc.controller")
public class ControllerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver configureInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

**WebAppInitializer.java**

```
package org.java.springmvc.bootstrap;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        root.setServletContext(servletContext);
        root.scan("org.java.springmvc.bootstrap");
        root.refresh();

        final Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("spring", new DispatcherServlet(root));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/*");
    }

}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
package org.java.springmvc.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public void home(final Writer writer) 
            throws IOException  {
        writer.append("<h2>Welcome, XML Free Spring MVC!</h2>");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/giris")
    public void giris(final Writer writer) 
            throws IOException  {
            writer.append("Giris");
    } 

}
```

**FilmController.java**

```
package org.java.springmvc.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.java.springmvc.model.Film;
import org.java.springmvc.model.Film.FilmTurleri;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/film")
public class FilmController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "filmler")
    public void filmler(final Writer writer) 
            throws IOException  {
        writer.append("<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9\"><title>...Filmler...</title>");
        writer.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/js/touch/sencha-touch-all.js\"></script>");
        writer.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/js/film/filmler.js\"></script>");
        writer.append("</head><body></body></html>");

    } 

    @RequestMapping (value = "/filmleriGetir", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, List<Film>> FilmleriGetir() {
        List<Film> movies = new ArrayList<Film>();

        // For testing...
        movies.add(new Film(0, "Birinci Film", "Birinci Yönetmen", 2015, FilmTurleri.Aksiyon));
        movies.add(new Film(0, "İkinci Film", "İkinci Yönetmen", 2015, FilmTurleri.Komedi));
        movies.add(new Film(0, "Üçüncü Film", "Üçüncü Yönetmen", 2015, FilmTurleri.Aile));

        Map<String, List<Film>> resp = new HashMap<String, List<Film>>();
        resp.put("filmListesi", movies);
        return resp;
    }

}
```

**Film.java**

```
package org.java.springmvc.model;

public class Film {

    public int Id;
    public String FilmAdi, Yonetmen;
    public int CikisTarihi;
    public FilmTurleri Turu;

    public enum FilmTurleri {
        Aksiyon, Komedi, Aile, Korku, Savas;
    }

    public Film(){

    }

    public Film(int id, String title, String director, int yearOfRelease, FilmTurleri tur)
    {
        super();
        this.Id = id;
        this.FilmAdi = title;
        this.Yonetmen = director;
        this.CikisTarihi = yearOfRelease;
        this.Turu = tur;
    }
    //getter, settings method
}
```

i have two questions:

1. if i write "http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/", the page displays.
   But if i write "http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/movies/index" i get this warning:

"WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'"

2. if i add a JSP page(Giris.jsp) under WebContent, i cannot display this page. must all page has a mapping? how can i display simple jsp page?

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/Giris.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

EDIT:
i changed a little.
My project structure like this:

[image]

i get this error:

Failed to load resource:

http://localhost:8080/js/film/filmler.js

http://localhost:8080/js/touch/sencha-touch-all.js

i thought a logic like that:

```
- there will be a jsp file including "*.js" files. (filmler.jsp)

- there are some methods returning json object in those *.js files. (FilmleriGetir method)
```

any advice for this logic?

Regards.

Comment: Could you add the file structure of your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In MovieController.java, you need to add '/'
   :

`@RequestMapping("/movies")`

2. You are using `servlet.addMapping("/*");` which means your `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` i.e Spring will intercept **every request** that comes to your application. Now, you don't have any `RequestMapping` for `Giris.jsp` in any controller, so Spring is throwing error as:  No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/Giris.jsp]

---

In order to show Giris.jsp page, your need to:

A] Add entry in/ make new controller with  `RequestMapping` for 'Giris.jsp', and set view as 'Giris'

eg:

```
   @Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Giris.jsp")
    public void home(final Writer writer) 
            throws IOException  {
            return 'Giris';
    }    
}
```

You would be better of using RequestMapping as `/giris` instead of `/Giris.jsp`, as it exposes that underlying technology is JSP.

B] place Giris.jsp file under `/WEB-INF/views/` folder.

Understand how `InternalResourceViewResolver` works. Taking reference of your `ControllerConfiguration`, When a view name is returned for controller as 'Giris',  InternalResourceViewResolver adds prefix and suffix as defined by you, and that page is shown. So, in case of view name 'Giris', page `'/WEB-INF/views/'+ 'Giris' + '.jsp'` will be rendered.

---

- According to [java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/namingconventions-139351.html), JSP (file) name should always begin with a lower-case letter. So use `giris.jsp` instead of `Giris.jsp`

---

---

EDIT(For modified question):

> Failed to load resource: http://localhost:8080/js/film/filmler.js

Understand that, as `DispatcherServlet` is mapped to `/*`, every request that comes to your web-app, is handled by `DispatcherServlet` i.e `Spring`.

Whenever you application comes across url http://localhost:8080/js/film/filmler.js, it knows that `DispatcherServlet` will handle that url. `DispatcherServlet` checks if there is any `RequestMapping` for the url(in controller).

Now, when you add url

> http://localhost:8080/js/film/filmler.js

there is no RequestMapping that would handle such kind of url, so you are getting a url.

For loading resources such as js files or image files, use `mvc:resources`.

eg:
For js files:
Put all your js files in directory `/WEB-INF/js/`.

Add mvc:resource mapping for js files in you configuration:

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/WEB-INF/js/" />
```

Now you you will be able to access your js files. If Spring comes across url such as `/js/film/filmler.js`, it will know know from mvc:resource mapping, for where to look for that file.

Goof mvc:resource for tutorials.

Comment: 1. "/" works, thanks. if i debug app, breakpoint in index method is firing. But after method finished i get this error: org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Comment: You should have index.jsp file placed as `/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp'.

Comment: EDIT: i changed a little.

i get this error:

Failed to load resource:

http://localhost:8080/js/film/filmler.js

http://localhost:8080/js/touch/sencha-touch-all.js

i thought a logic like that:

- there will be a jsp file including "*.js" files. (filmler.jsp)

- there are some methods returning json object in those *.js files. (FilmleriGetir method)
any advice for this logic?

Regards.

Comment: Have edited my answer to include the solution to the problem that you are facing while accessing js files.

Comment: i've found a way adding resources dynamically. i put my js files under WEB-INF. But i still get the error.                                                             `@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfigurationContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/js/");
    }

}`

Comment: Are you sure that you have added js files under `WEB-INF/js/` folder, and src in <script> is like '/js/xxx'?

Comment: my last project structure and error is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986950/sencha-touch-2-the-key-minimum-ui-is-not-recognized-and-ignored